# TamperMonkey JS UserScript bypassing a waiting time

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

Trying to write a **userscript** for **TamperMonkey** to be running in **browser** for **bypassing a waiting time** as a training.
Here is the script used in that page:

```
var timeout;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#countdown').each(function(i, e) {
        if (timeout) return;

        timeout = setTimeout(tick, 1000);

        function tick() {
            console.log('Tick');
            var remaining = parseInt($(e).find(".seconds").text()) - 1;
            if (remaining <= 0) {
                $(e).css('visibility', 'hidden');
            } else {
                $(e).find(".seconds").text(remaining.toString());
                setTimeout(tick, 1000);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

JQuery is enabled in my script and is working, I was able to disable/enable some web elements, here the question is just about the 'waiting time'.

Is it possible to bypass it?

Do I/you need any extra information regarding it?

I tried some pieces of code, still with no success:

for example:

```
// Tried the below variables with a hope to override them in therms they exists.
// wasn't sure if even the usage or approach be totally correct.
let seconds = 0;
let remaining = 0;
let tick = 1;
let timeout = 60;

$(document).ready(function () {
    // altered some elements.

    seconds = 0;
    remaining = 0;
    tick = 1;
    timeout = 60;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables you declare in your userscript are not referenced at all in the page's script, so I don't know what you're expecting the userscript to affect.

Since the page's script retrieves the seconds remaining from a `.seconds` element, you can modify that element to remove the timeout:

```
document.querySelector('.seconds').textContent = '1';
```

and that's it. This way you won't have to wait for it to count down, it'll finish immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes those were some shots in the dark to test and learn, I also tried some codes like :   //   $("#countdown").find(".seconds").text(remaining.toString());
    // $("#seconds").text("0"); earlier, but they didn't work as expected, your code did quite well, but the problem was the page button will give this warning: " Skipped countdown", I was hopeful everything be in JS, maybe part of this check be on the server. What is your opinion?

Comment: It's impossible to say without seeing the code that produces `Skipped countdown`. Might be verification on the server, might be something else done by the JS which is bypassable

Comment: Anyway thanks, let me know if you had anything else to add here, it will help me a lot.

Comment: I don't see anything referencing `.seconds` or a timeout on view-source:https://www.file-upload.com/ - if you're wondering about the "Skipped countdown", you can put a [MCVE] in an edit to the question

Comment: TBH obviously there is some hidden extra check at their site, I don't know what it is and where it is located, tried and was able to change several parts, but don't know where it might be checked, so don't know how to stimulate a similar minimal scenario. BTW if you check your script with any file there you may get the same result.